# unable to insert data into mysql no error display

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

/*i want to insert data with the form and written simple code for it. Html part is working well.post table is created in database but this code unable to insert data in database. Please help me*/
    
        
            Inserting new posts

```
    </head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="insert_post_1.php"        enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="600" align="center" border="10">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="yellow" colspan="6">
                <h1>Insert New Post Here</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Title:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Author:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="author" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Keywords:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="keywords" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Post Content:</td>
            <td><textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="25"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

/*html has no issue it works perfectly fine but with this php code i am unable to detect the problem. while clicking Publish button it is not inserting data to database*/

```
    if($post_title == '' or $post_keywords == '' or $post_author == '' or $post_content == ''){
    echo "<script>alert('Any of the fields is empty')</script>";
    exit();
    }
    else{
    move_uploaded_file($post_temp, "images/$post_image");
/*this part of code is not running and hence unable to insert data to database*/    
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO "
            . "posts (`post_id`, `post_title`, `post_date`, `post_author`, `post_image`, `post_keywords`, `post_content`)"
            . " VALUES (NULL, $post_title, $post_date, $post_author, $post_image, $post_keywords, $post_content)";

    if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
        echo "<center><h1>Post Published Successfully</h1></center>";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try to add a else statement to check whether query runs or not...

Comment: You are passing in several variables assumed to be strings, which are not single-quoted.  See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/541091) for examples on how to correctly quote these. However, it is vulnerable to SQL injection in this form, and that is best handled by adopting either PDO or MySQLi with `prepare()/execute()` instead of `mysql_connect()/mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the mysql extension, comment this block

```
if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
    echo "<center><h1>Post Published Successfully</h1></center>";
}
```

and add this below

```
mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<center><h1>Post Published Successfully</h1></center>";
```

in order to see what's the error

Comment: error is Connected successfully Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) how to correct

Comment: Most likely there's something wrong with the database credentials you've supplied (or forgot to) in the piece of code that makes the connection to MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to look in to [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) documentation:

`mysql_query` is depricated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

to check error in mysql:

```
try{
   // Run your query:
}
catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `mysql_query()`, despite being deprecated, will not throw an exception. You are essentially telling the OP to rewrite all the code to PDO, then check for errors.

Comment: I am encourage OP not to use deprecated functions. Anyways, somebody will find this post useful. Thanks for down voting though..